# Elastic Search Information On ElasticProperty

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Can anyone tell me what this means?

[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]

I've been looking through documentation and I just don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

It is an annotation that Nest uses to [infer information](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/index-type-inference.html) about how to tell ElasticSearch to index/analyze the field. In this case, it says that this field should be [analyzed](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping-intro.html#_index_2).